React Native Boiler plate that is not as complex as Ignite
Been building a few mobile apps with react native for quite a while now, however most boiler plate apps are a bit sophisticated like the Ignite boiler plate. Wondering if anyone in the community has come across an easier to use react native boiler plate.
Many Thanks
I have tried the Ignite boiler plate and also the boiler plate that looks like this image https://cdn.dribbble.com/userupload/5815631/file/original-5b6d7bdf59defe4156b0cb25607ab182.png?compress=1&resize=1024x768.
Im excepting a boilerplate that has the bottom navigation and the drawer navigation that is not as complex as Ignite

Why not create your own and reuse it for you apps?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

@johnhaup. Alright. Will Create My own. Thanks!
